# LLVM: Where does function usage (constant value cast) come from?

Tags: llvm

My goal is to replace all call/invoke instructions to an original function with call/invoke instructions to a new function.
Sometimes there is an additional usage that I don't know what to do with.

To investigate I am running the following module pass:

```
bool ControlFlowDiversity::runOnModule(Module &M) {
  for (Function& f : M) {
    DEBUG(dbgs() << f.getName() << ", uses: " << f.getNumUses());
    DEBUG(dbgs() << ", hasAddressTaken: " << f.hasAddressTaken() << "\n");
    // DEBUG(dbgs() << "hasMetadata: " << f.hasMetadata() << "\n");
    for (auto i = f.use_begin(), e = f.use_end(); i != e; ++i) {
      i->dump();
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

[test1.c]

```
void x();
int main() { x(); }
void x() { }
```

[test2.c]

```
void x() { }
int main() { x(); }
```

[output1]

```
main, uses: 0, hasAddressTaken: 0
x, uses: 1, hasAddressTaken: 0
  call void @x()
```

[output2]

```
x, uses: 2, hasAddressTaken: 1
  call void @x()
void (...)* bitcast (void ()* @x to void (...)*)
main, uses: 0, hasAddressTaken: 0
```

Where does the additional usage come from? It is a `Constant` (cast).
Is the address stored in some metedata/table? What is it good for?
When I am replacing the usages, do I have to replace the constant with a new constant or can I simply delete it?
Dumping the module shows exactly what I expect. It contains no sign of the additional usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constant usages are only cleaned up if you explicitly ask for them to be so- they are effectively garbage collected rather than cleaned up immediately.

http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1Constant.html#a50d0911852017f2168de329f53d8568d

Simply call this function and you should find the usages removed.